# KML from PostGIS Geometry into Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, kml

im getting the KML value from my postgis database.. `st_askml()`

And the output is like this:

`"<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-99.999999990686774,48.499999959021807 -99.999999990686774,47.999999988824129 -99.500000020489097,47.999999988824129 -99.500000020489097,48.499999959021807 -99.999999990686774,48.499999959021807</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>"`

Now i need to display them on a Openlayers Map i got.

Layer: 
`var KML_Layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('KML');`

Formatting code:

```
function GetFeaturesFromKMLString (strKML) {
var format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
        'internalProjection': options.projections.source, //EPSG:3785/900913
        'externalProjection': options.projections.display //EPSG:4326
    });

return format.read(strKML);
};
```

Adding the feature to the layer:

`KML_Layer.addFeatures(value.st_askml);`

Debuggin info:

value.st_askml = The output format i pasted earlier in topic.

After running it trough the `GetFeaturesFromKMLString()` its set to `[]` (No value here)

How can i get this to display correctly on the map?

Comment: Can you try manually adding the <kml><placemark>...</placemark></kml> bits around the strKML?

Comment: Done and failed =/
I tried adding it like this: `<kml><placemark>'+value.st_askml+'</placemark></kml>` - Before it was sent to the KML reader. And also tried inserting the string directly to the vector. no result still .. `Console.log()` still gives me `[]`

Comment: Please show the exact string you are putting into addFeatures()? Did you pass an xmlns for whatever version of KML you are trying to use? Does it work if you use the examples from http://projects.opengeo.org/mobile/browser/demos/OL-investigation/openlayers/tests/Format/KML.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST_AsKML()` function doesnt return you valid kml file for openlayers or google earth. the result you have seen being formed from raw coordinates for kml file. you can achive this with following code which @BradHards has mentioned.

put your output between `<Placemark>your output</Placemark>`. you can try it whether works or not with google earth. i have tested it and has worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
  <Style id="0">    
  </Style> 
    <Placemark>           
     <Polygon>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
       <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
        -99.999999990686774,48.499999959021807 
        -99.999999990686774,47.999999988824129 
        -99.500000020489097,47.999999988824129 
        -99.500000020489097,48.499999959021807 
        -99.999999990686774,48.499999959021807
        </coordinates>
       </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
     </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: So the st_askml wont work with a JSON request. i have to make the request get an xml/kml document?

Comment: Pulled it off by pasting the result as an XML/KML instead of Json :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer has an invalid `xmlns`. I think the correct one will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
 <Style id="0">    
 </Style> 
 <Placemark>           
  <Polygon>
   <outerBoundaryIs>
    <LinearRing>
     <coordinates>
      -99.999999990686774,48.499999959021807 
      -99.999999990686774,47.999999988824129 
      -99.500000020489097,47.999999988824129 
      -99.500000020489097,48.499999959021807 
      -99.999999990686774,48.499999959021807
     </coordinates>
    </LinearRing>
   </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
 </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```